# How to stop web.config inheritance from the Child application

Tags: c#, web-config

I know that we can stop inheritance of the web.config files from the root web.config file like this:

This attribute below used in the root web.config file will prevent an application from passing its configuration as a default to child applications.

```
<!-- Root web.config file -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" />
      <!-- other configuration attributes -->
    </system.web> 
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But i just want to know that is there any attribute or somethiing by which i can do this by my child application's web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much you can do unless you're on IIS7, in which case you can use configuration locking as described [here on www.iis.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration)